# Access nested property in pymongo

Tags: python, pymongo

I'm trying to access "msgId", which is nested. However, it returns the property name instead of the value. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Code:

```py
def get_captain_message_id(game_id, user):
    data = {
        "gameId":game_id,
        "messageIds":str(user.id)
    }

    return mongo.db['GameData'].find_one(data)['msgId']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're trying to access a property of the inner document as if it belonged to the outer one.

First you have to change your query `data` to match the document whose `messageIds` object contains the `user.id` property.

```
data = {
        "gameId":game_id,
        f"messageIds.{user.id}": {"$exists": True}
    }
```

Then you can access `msgId` value with the appropriate indexing pipeline:

```
return mongo.db['GameData'].find_one(data)['messageIds'][str(user.id)]['msgId']
```